# R igraph loop in two list

Tags: r, list, loops, attributes, igraph

I have two list object and I want to write a code to run both of them. My first list object is `"rt.lc"` that has 12 igraphs in it. My second list is `"edges"` that has 68 edge attributes in it.
I want to delete these edge attributes in 12 igraph objects. I can only delete one edge attribute in each iteration.

My code looks like this:

```
rt.lc.new <- list ()
for (i in (rt.lc)){

  for (j in (edges)){

    rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc[[i]],j)
  }
}
```

delete_edge_attr is a igraph function that delete only one edge attributes in each attempt.

I used this long and slow code to deal with the problem:

My rt.lc list is:

```
rt.lc. <- list("Civil.Liberties", "Foreign.Policy", "Women.s.Rights", "Workers..Rights", 
    "Political.Polarisation", "Kurdish.Peace.Process", "Parallel.State", 
    "HDP.Election.Slogans", "Related.With.Election", "CHP.Election.Slogans", 
    "AKP.Election.Slogans", "MHP.Election.Slogans")
```

My edges list is:

```
edges <- list("tweet_id", "tweet_text", "tweet_created_at", "in_reply_to_status_id_str", 
"in_reply_to_screen_name", "retweet_count", "favorite_count", 
"machine_translated_language", "geo_lat", "geo_long", "country_code", 
"location_full_name", "source", "truncated", "user_created_at", 
"person_name", "statuses_count", "friends_count", "followers_count", 
"user_profile_location", "user_profile_language", "media_url", 
"expanded_urls", "tweet_urls", "hashtag_text", "usermentions_screen_name", 
"retweet", "retweet_id_str", "retweet_text", "retweet_created_at", 
"retweet_user_created_at", "retweet_person_name", "retweet_statuses_count", 
"retweet_friends_count", "retweet_followers_count", "retweet_urls", 
"retweet_hashtag_text", "retweet_usermentions_screen_name", 
"geo_type", "geo_bounding_box", "country", "favourites_count", 
"listed_count", "retweet_favorited", "retweet_retweeted", 
"retweet_favorite_count", "retweet_retweet_count", "retweet_in_reply_to_status_id", 
"retweet_in_reply_to_screen_name", "retweet_in_reply_to_user_id", 
"retweet_favourites_count", "retweet_listed_count", "retweet_location", 
"retweet_following", "retweet_geo_type", "retweet_geo_lat", 
"retweet_geo_long", "retweet_usermentions_name", "retweet_usermentions_id", 
"retweet_media_id", "retweet_media_type", "retweet_media_url", 
"retweet_media_expanded_url", "row_id", "posi.date", "mentions", 
"hashtag_combined", "hashtags_combined")
```

Update: I used this long and slow code to deal with the problem:

```
rt.lc.new <- list()
for(i in colnames(hash.by.cat)){
  cat("...")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_vertex_attr(rt.lc[[i]],"friends_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_vertex_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"comp")
  #rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"tweet_id")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"tweet_text")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"tweet_created_at")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"in_reply_to_status_id_str")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"in_reply_to_screen_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"favorite_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"machine_translated_language")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"geo_lat")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"geo_long")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"country_code")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"location_full_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"source")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"truncated")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"user_created_at")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"person_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"friends_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"followers_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"user_profile_location")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"user_profile_language")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"media_url")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"expanded_urls")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"tweet_urls")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"hashtag_text")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"usermentions_screen_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_id_str")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_created_at")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_user_created_at")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_person_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_statuses_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_friends_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_followers_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_urls")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_hashtag_text")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_usermentions_screen_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"geo_type")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"geo_bounding_box")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"country")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"favourites_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"listed_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_favorited")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_retweeted")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_favorite_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_retweet_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_in_reply_to_status_id")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_in_reply_to_screen_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_in_reply_to_user_id")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_favourites_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_listed_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_location")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_following")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_geo_type")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_geo_lat")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_geo_long")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_usermentions_name")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_usermentions_id")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_media_id")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_media_type")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_media_url")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_media_expanded_url")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"row_id")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"mentions")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"hashtag_combined")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"hashtags_combined")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"statuses_count")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"retweet_text")
  rt.lc.new[[i]] <- delete_edge_attr(rt.lc.new[[i]],"posi.date")
  cat(i,"\n")
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that can be used to test possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I know that it is difficult to do something without reproducible example but I did my best to give more in depth about my question. Thanks